# Angular2 - How to reload current component when underlying data has changed

Tags: angular, material-design

I have a TaskComponent which pulls only OPEN tasks from the web service and displays in the template. 
This template has a 'MARK COMPLETED' button, the onSubmit() of this button changes the status of the task to CLOSED via http POST.

Now that the task status has changed, it should no longer be displayed in the current page. I do not want to navigate out of this page, but want to make sure the completed task is not displayed.

If I refresh the page, the completed tasks do not show as expected. How I achieve this without refreshing the page ?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tasks',
    template: `<div mdl class="mdl-grid demo-content">

          <div class="demo-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
                <h3>Tasks Page</h3>

              <div *ngFor="#task of tasks" class="demo-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
                <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand mdl-color--teal-300">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{task.taskname}}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
                {{task.taskdesc}}
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">                
                <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">{{task.assignedto}}</a>


                <a *ngIf="task.taskstatus=='OPEN'" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" (click)="onClickMark(task)">MARK COMPLETED</a>               


                <a [routerLink]="['/EditTask']" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" (click)="onClick1(task)">EDIT</a>               
                </div>
             </div>          
          </div>            
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,MDL]

})

export class TasksComponent {

    public tasks: Object[];
    data: any;
    userEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService, private sharedService: SharedService,private router: Router) { }


    onClickMark(task){
       this.data  = task;
       this.apartmentService.markCompleted(this.data);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the task that is marked as completed from the `tasks` list :

```
onClickMark(task){
   this.data  = task;
   this.apartmentService.markCompleted(this.data);     
   var index = this.tasks.findIndex((task) => this.data = task);
   this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
}
```

If your markCompleted is asynchronous, you need to return an observable or promise to notify the calling component. Here is a sample:

```
onClickMark(task){
   this.data  = task;
   this.apartmentService.markCompleted(this.data).subscribe(() => {     
     var index = this.tasks.findIndex((task) => this.data = task);
     this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
   });
}
```

Comment: minor change in this line .. var index = this.tasks.findIndex((task) => this.data==task); ... Thanks alot.. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `markCompleted()` method seems to do an async call to the server. To be able to chain additional code for when `markCompleted()` is done, it needs to return a `Promise` or `Observable`. Then you can chain more code like:

```
onClickMark(task){
   this.data  = task;
   this.apartmentService.markCompleted(this.data)
   .then(result => this.data = []); // with Promise
   .subscribe(result => this.data = []); // with Observable
}
```